# Parallelize a Do nested

Tags: parallelization

I have a nested `Do` and I need to parallelize the outer `Do`. I replaced the `Do` by `ParalleleDo` in the outer `Do` but with this I don't have `out`. Why?

The Do is some like:

```
do = {}; 
   Do[Print[i]; 
         data = DeleteCases[Reap[Do[Sow[1 + i], {i, 3}]], Null] *i;
            do = Append[do, data], {i, 4}];
```

The out of this is:

```
 do = {{{{2,3,4}}},{{{4,6,8}}},{{{6,9,12}}},{{{8,12,16}}}}
```

Then, I need that each list be process by one different kernel, I put `ParallelDo`:

```
 do = {}; 
   ParallelDo[Print[i]; 
         data = DeleteCases[Reap[Do[Sow[1 + i], {i, 3}]], Null] *i;
            do = Append[do, data], {i, 4}];
```

And the out is:

```
 do = {}
```

Why?

Really my `Do`is more complex but this summarizes why I need to only parallelize the outer `Do`.

Comment: Have you tried using `ParallelTable` ?

`ParallelTable[
 DeleteCases[Reap[Do[Sow[1 + i], {i, 3}]], Null]*i, {i, 3}]`

Comment: It sounds like you're asking two questions - "I don't have `out`. Why?" and how to parallelize your particular construct, is that right?

Comment: Using a FrontEnd-dependend command like `Print` that often in parallelized code won't improve performance. Actually, using `Print` slows down _everything_. You are probably looking for `ParallelTable`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have 2 different `do` variables: one the first `do` before the `ParallelDo`, and another within the parallel do, which is the *declared* in each kernel, and lives only in there. If you want to have such a *global* variable you would need to set it as shared variable. But even if you do it that way, you will have a possible race condition and only some of the kernels will actually update the *right* variable. You can also set a *shared function* to update only a *downvalue* of `do`, and that may work:

```
do[_] = {}
SetSharedFunction[do]
ParallelDo[Print[i];
  data = DeleteCases[Reap[Do[Sow[1 + i], {i, 3}]], Null]*i;
  Print[data];
  do[$KernelID] = Append[do[$KernelID], data], {i, 4}];
```

And you can join the results in different ways, like doing another `Do`, or better a `Table` or even better a `ParallelTable`:

```
DeleteCases[ParallelTable[do[$KernelID], {Kernels[]}], {}]
```

But of course, all that is just the wrong way to do the parallel task because usually you don't want to use `Do` but `Table`, and in this case `ParallelTable` may be much better in the first place:

```
ParallelTable[Print[i];
 Table[1 + j, {j, 3}]*i, {i, 4}]
```

I also didn't see the need of that `Reap`/`Sow` structure within a `Do`, that's again what `Table` does (and simpler because you won't need `DeleteCases`), and also try to avoid using the same variable for nested structures, that may lead to hard to debug issues.

That returns the same result as your first `Do` with the only difference of list nesting, but probably that shouldn't be an issue, and if it is, it is just as easy as wrapping your results. (And I think that `Print` should go away once you see how that's working).

Comment: I would add the following rule of thumb: when you parallize, don't use shared values to aggregate results. Every time a shared symbol is updated, the values have to be distributed to all the kernels and this leads to communication overhead. Instead, you simply want each kernel to do its own thing and then come back to you with a big block of results that can be mashed together with the results from the other kernels. This is basically what `ParallelTable` does for constructing large lists and it's the best way to leverage parallelization.